# Split and tile a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
df:

id .  city .  state . person1 . P1phone1 . P1phone2 . person2 . P2phone1 . P2phone2
1 .   Ghut .  TY    . Jeff    . 32131    . 4324     . Bill    . 213123   . 31231   
2 .   Ffhs .  TY    . Ron     . 32131    . 4324     . Bill    . 213123   . 31231   
3 .   Tyuf .  TY    . Jeff    . 32131    . 4324     . Tyler   . 213123   . 31231
```

I want it to look like this:

```
df:
id .  city .  state . person  . phone1   . phone2
1 .   Ghut .  TY    . Jeff    . 32131    . 4324  
2 .   Ghut .  TY    . Bill    . 213123   . 31231  
3 .   Ffhs .  TY    . Ron     . 32131    . 4324  
4 .   Ffhs .  TY    . Bill    . 213123   . 31231   
5 .   Tyuf .  TY    . Jeff    . 32131    . 4324
6 .   Tyuf .  TY    . Tyler   . 213123   . 31231
```

I'm having quite a hard time trying to do that. Can someone help?

Comment: I seriously don't recommend hardcoding rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just slice the dataframe into two:

```
In [20]: df1 = df[['city','state','person1','P1phone1','P1phone2']]

In [21]: df2 = df[['city','state','person2','P2phone1','P2phone2']]
```

and then make sure they have the same columns:

```
In [27]: df1.columns = ['city','state','person','phone1','phone2']

In [28]: df2.columns = ['city','state','person','phone1','phone2']
```

And then append one onto the other:

```
In [29]: df1.append(df2)
Out[29]: 
   city state person  phone1 phone2
0  Ghut    TY   Jeff   32131   4324
1  Ffhs    TY    Ron   32131   4324
2  Tyuf    TY   Jeff   32131   4324
0  Ghut    TY   Bill  213123  31231
1  Ffhs    TY   Bill  213123  31231
2  Tyuf    TY  Tyler  213123  31231
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df

id   city   state  person1  P1phone1  P1phone2  person2  P2phone1  P2phone2
1    Ghut   TY     Jeff     32131     4324      Bill     213123    31231   
2    Ffhs   TY     Ron      32131     4324      Bill     213123    31231   
3    Tyuf   TY     Jeff     32131     4324      Tyler    213123    31231  

df = df.set_index(['city', 'state'])
df.columns = np.tile(df.columns[:3].values,  2)
```

---

Using `df.append`

```
df = df.iloc[:, :3].append(df.iloc[:, 3:]).reset_index()
df 

   city state person1  P1phone1  P1phone2
0  Ghut    TY    Jeff     32131      4324
1  Ffhs    TY     Ron     32131      4324
2  Tyuf    TY    Jeff     32131      4324
3  Ghut    TY    Bill    213123     31231
4  Ffhs    TY    Bill    213123     31231
5  Tyuf    TY   Tyler    213123     31231
```

---

Using `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3].append(df.iloc[:, 3:])]).reset_index()
df 

   city state person1  P1phone1  P1phone2
0  Ghut    TY    Jeff     32131      4324
1  Ffhs    TY     Ron     32131      4324
2  Tyuf    TY    Jeff     32131      4324
3  Ghut    TY    Bill    213123     31231
4  Ffhs    TY    Bill    213123     31231
5  Tyuf    TY   Tyler    213123     31231
```

Comment: yeah, yeah, I like that

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Yeah... playing with column names can get tiring fast ;-)

Comment: I just think it is pd.wide_to_long question :)

Comment: @Wen Hah, your favourite kind ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes :) LOL

Answer (score 1):

try this brother

```
   pd.concat(df.loc[:,['id','city','state','person1','P1phone1','P1phone2']].
rename(columns = {'person1' : 'person', 'P1phone1' : 'phone1', 'P1phone2' : 'phone2'),
    df.loc[:,['id','city','state','person2','P2phone1','P2phone2']].
rename(columns = {'person1' : 'person', 'P2phone1' : 'phone1', 'P2phone2' : 'phone2'), axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typically `pd.wide_to_long` question

Try this

```
df=df.rename(columns={'P1phone1':'phone1P1','P1phone2':'phone2P1','P2phone1':'phone1P2','P2phone2':'phone2P2'})

   pd.wide_to_long(df,['person','phone1P','phone2P'],i=['id','city','state'],j='age').reset_index().drop('age',1)
Out[364]: 
   id  city state person  phone1P  phone2P
0   1  Ghut    TY   Jeff    32131     4324
1   1  Ghut    TY   Bill   213123    31231
2   2  Ffhs    TY    Ron    32131     4324
3   2  Ffhs    TY   Bill   213123    31231
4   3  Tyuf    TY   Jeff    32131     4324
5   3  Tyuf    TY  Tyler   213123    31231
```

Answer (score 1):

I was too slow with this but here's my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#define column names for the result df.
# another way to ensure the same column names: colnames = df.columns.values[:6] 
colnames = ['identity', 'city', 'state', 'person', 'phone1', 'phone2']

#split the original df into two. 
df1 = df.iloc[:, :6]
df2 = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3], df.iloc[:, 6:]], axis=1)

#reset the column names so that both dfs have same colnames
df1.columns, df2.columns = colnames, colnames

#concatenate the two
result = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)

identity    city    state   person  phone1  phone2
0           1   Ghut    TY  Jeff    32131   4324
1           2   Ffhs    TY  Ron     32131   4324
2           3   Tyuf    TY  Jeff    32131   4324
3           1   Ghut    TY  Bill    213123  31231
4           2   Ffhs    TY  Bill    213123  31231
5           3   Tyuf    TY  Tyler   213123  31231
```